# Inner join SQL 2 tables

Tags: sql

I need help making a inner join.

I have to tables, one named `Cycletype` and the other `Cykler`.

`Cycletype` has a column named `Type`. In this column I have named the different type of `cycles`.

On my other table `Cykler` I have some columns with data about the `cycles` and a `fk_cycletype_Id` column so that they can link to eachother.

My problem is that I dont know how to write the code in my CS file.

This is what I have written so far(not working):

```
SELECT * FROM Cykler 
    INNER JOIN Cycletype 
    ON Cykler.fk_cycletype_Id = id 
    WHERE id = @id
```

I havent much experience with inner joins so I am completely lost and I am in big need of help.

On my frontend page I have 6 different pictures with the different types of `cycles` so that when I click on `mountainbikes`, for example, it should show all `mountainbikes` from `Cykler`. But i need help if anyone can, please?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/entX4.jpg

picture description of the tables

Comment: Can you provide the key column name for Cycletype?

Comment: The key coloumn name for Cycletype is Cycletype_Id

Comment: Please edit your post because the image you provide does not fit with your question (the tables are named different)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of your columns names...

But...is it possible that your "id" column exists in both tables... thus naming the table fixes the issue...

```
SELECT * FROM Cykler 
INNER JOIN Cycletype ON Cykler.fk_cycletype_Id = Cycletype.id 
WHERE Cycletype.id = @id
```

Comment: @Nicolaj Please put the image in your question, and also, the table names in that photo are *not* what's in your question.

Comment: I had linked the wrong image before, so now I link the right one. The previous one had a wrong table in it. http://imgur.com/RnL93cY

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from Cykler c
inner join CycleType ct on ct.ID = c.fk_cycletype_Id 
where c.ID = @ID
```

You could then access the Type's by selecting ct.Type, or whatever the name of the Type field is in CycleTypes.

**EDIT -- after seeing your second picture**

This should work:

```
select ct.Type
from Cykler c
inner join Cycletype ct on ct.Cycletype_Id = c.fk_cycletype_Id
where c.ID = @ID
```

I put ct.Type in the select, but of course you could select whatever you need.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean when you write C after select * 
from Cykler.

Comment: I'm just giving the table an alias so that it can be referenced in the join. The c could be whatever you choose, it just represents Cykler in this instance.

Comment: I just saw your photo. From that, I'm not sure you have anything set up in CykelTyper that is a link to Cycletype?

Comment: Oh I didnt think I needed that only one linked to the other and it would work?

Comment: I edited my answer after seeing your most recent picture.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and comments, your query should be :

```
SELECT * FROM Cykler 
INNER JOIN Cycletype 
ON Cykler.fk_cycletype_Id = Cycletype.Cycletype_Id
WHERE Cycletype_Id = @id
```

Comment: I get this error message when I run the page: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.